# This short page puts a default color of purple, can not determine why

Tags: html

bring this up and admin is purple, then will correctly do gray and lightgray. Can not determine where the purple comes from. Tried in 3 major browser, never happened before and can not determine where this purple color comes from. Have whittled code down to these few lines but still no success.

```
  <HTML>


 <a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color='GRAY'" 
 onmouseout="this.style.color='LIGHTGRAY'">admin</a> 

 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This is not well formed modern HTML source code. It's incomplete, missing tags, uses a link element as if it's an HTML 3.2 placeholder anchor, uses deprecated JavaScript event handling, and I strongly recommend simply deleting what you have here, and starting over using a [modern HTML5 template](https://github.com/iandevlin/html5bones/blob/master/clean-templates/main-template-no-comments.html) instead.

Comment: The code was made that way and should work. It does work except for the initial blue color of 'admin'. If you are going to make assumptions you should read the question and perhaps answer the question instead of extraneous comments that are not helpful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "if you say so" and "definitely not". This code is absolutely horrid and should under no circumstance "just work". It should in fact be expected to break differently (and not necessarily even noticably) in every browser.

Answer (score 2):

In most browsers, the default color for visited links is purple*. It's initially showing up as purple because 1) it's a link you've clicked on before and 2) you don't have any styles overriding the browser's default color for visited links.

If you want the text to always be light gray when the mouse isn't hovering over it, you should use CSS to set that as the default color for links, like this:

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #333333;
}

a:hover {
  color:#CCCCCC; 
}
```

```html
<p><a href="http://yahoo.com">Example Link #1</a></p>

<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Example Link #2</a></p>

<p><a href="http://www.bing.com">Example Link #3</a></p>
```

*You can check this in:

Firefox by going to Tools > Options > Content > Colors

In IE by going to Settings > Options > General Tab > Appearance > Colors

In Opera by going to Settings > Preferences > Webpages

([Chrome is different](https://superuser.com/questions/726380/change-color-of-visited-links-in-chrome-33))

NOTE: You might annoy site visitors by making visited links the exact same color as unvisited links. You may want to consider letting those be a different color, even if you don't want them purple.

Comment: Thank you so much for your expert answer. Just what I was looking for. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

 <a href="#"  style="color: LIGHTGRAY;"  onmouseover="this.style.color='GRAY'" onmouseout="this.style.color='LIGHTGRAY'">admin</a> 

 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Just add the **`style="color: LIGHTGRAY;"`**,
works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/e4yzL8bz/1/

Comment: It does not work. It start with "admin" in blue. It is not supposed to. It should start in one of the gray's listed in the code. The question is where the heck does it get the blue that "admin" starts with??